# Sub-Queries and MYSQL

Tags: mysql

For my class we were given an assignment related to sub-queries and my professor is generally good at explaining code I struggled to pick up on what the core principals are for this section.

Here is the code for the tables and the beginning of what I think I may need to do

```
CREATE TABLE WEBSERVER 
( IP CHAR(30), 
vendor CHAR(30), 
os CHAR(30), 
location CHAR(30), 
PRIMARY KEY(IP) 
);

CREATE TABLE TRAFFIC 
( id INT, 
tdate DATE , 
ttime TIME, 
SourceIP CHAR(30), 
Protocol CHAR(10), 
WEBSERVER_IP CHAR(30), 
packetsize FLOAT, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (WEBSERVER_IP) REFERENCES WEBSERVER(IP)
)
```

This is what I have so far and am struggling with where to go from here:

```
select count(protocol), Protocol from traffic group by protocol
```

**This is the question:**

Find the frequency of the connections to each protocol type. (ratio = (number of connections to a protocol) / (the total number of connections)

–HINT: You need to use a subquery for this question)

Comment: gosh I hope your prof (from your profile page) doesn't read that :)  Maybe rewrite the top part and say "Though my professor is very good, I am struggling"

Comment: That is a good point. Just a little stressed about trying to figure this out and what not.

Comment: fear not Anthony. Some of us are on other questions now. We swoop back. Have a coke or something. In the meantime do us a favor by loading up a sqlfiddle.com on left pane. So we can jam it out. And paste back the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select protocol, count(*)/(select count(*) from traffic) as freq
from traffic
group by protocol
```

If your table had entries like this:

```
create table traffic (protocol char(10));
insert into traffic values ('TCP'), ('UDP'), ('TCP');
```

Your result will be:

```
| protocol | freq   |
|----------|--------|
|      TCP | 0.6667 |
|      UDP | 0.3333 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b699f/2

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was getting close to what I was wanting to get but there was no example from our webpage regarding putting the sub-queries inside of the original select statement so I wasn't 100% sure if that is what I needed to do.